# Active admin defining scope for custom page

Tags: activeadmin

I have created a custom page by using register_page method. I want to display result by defining scope. I know how to use scope for a model, but have no idea how to define scope for custom page. How do I define the scope?

Answer (score 0):

You should register resouce with alias for this:

`ActiveAdmin.register Post, as: 'post_statistics' do`

But if you have opportunity to not use ActiveAdmin - please don't use it. It will save you a lot of time and nerves.